# wp Plugin Admin panel checkbox unchecked after submit

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, checkbox, plugins

I am developing a plugin and I have 2 checkboxes in the admin panel. My code looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="vsuc_checkbox1" name="vsuc_checkbox1" value="style2"> value="style1" >
function vsuc_register_settings() {
    register_setting('vsuc_option_group', 'vsuc_checkbox1');
```

and then I have a :

```
$checkboxCheck = get_option( 'vsuc_checkbox1' ); 
if ( $checkboxCheck){
echo ' <style...'
```

The code Works, everything works, I just want to have the Checkbox selected stay checked.
And it's worth mentioning that I have 2 checkboxes and I want to be able to check only one of them.

Can someone please help me make this store the option that the checkbox was checked?

Comment: **style1** is being saved as value and then you're checking it with 1 so it will be always false, and you will get an unchecked checkbox. either changes your saving value in the value attribute or change the checkable value in `checked()` function.

Comment: You are totally right! I've changed it right now and it works! But if I want to be able to check only one of the checkboxes, how can i do it?

Comment: I have suggested to you yesterday, that you should use the radio button instead of the checkbox if you're trying to choose 1 value between multiple options. The checkbox should be used to store multiple values into an array or to build a yes/no toogle not to value switchers